# Nginx prevent static files from being served when user is not logged into Flask app

Tags: python, nginx, flask, flask-login

When having a Flask application deployed with Nginx and Gunicorn, is it possible to prevent static files being served from Nginx when the user is not logged in? I'm using flask-login to control user access.

Comment: Show the code that defines the flask view function that gives access to the static files.

Comment: Not Flask is serving the static files, but Nginx is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle static/media file permission on flask?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28084065/how-to-handle-static-media-file-permission-on-flask)