# How to handle static/media file permission on flask?

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I've created an application in which media files(files that are uploaded by users, not css/js) are served statically by another server on the subdomain like: `media.example.com/path/to/image.jpg`. How can I limit access to the images so that only certain people who are logged in and have permission can see them?

Please note that persmissions on page in which an image is displayed are working but I want to further limit access to the images themselves so image urls can't be shared.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Serve your image through Flask instead of your web server, treat it like any other url with permissions. Nginx is obviously a much better choice to serve your static files but it won't integrate with Flask.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I think static files should not be served by flask on production? Are there any caveats that I'm not aware of?

Comment: You are correct, that's not optimal, I always serve static files through a web server, but that won't do for what you require. The downside is it won't be as light as serving your images through a web server, this will be more noticeable when your traffic increases.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be seeking a solution in which the webserver (nginx) knows things which only the application (flask) knows: whether the requesting browser has authenticated their session.

It might be possible to devise some crafty solution such that the application leaves enough clues lying around for nginx to inspect, but it is not common and, if you're asking the question, probably too tricky-woo for you to perfect a reliable solution.

For example, the application might write to an htaccess file and implement an `auth_basic_user_file` via the browser.  But I wouldn't recommend it.

Or you might attempt [security by obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) by putting the static files into a randomly created subdirectory. eg `/static/12340A9BN34/secret_img.jpg`.  But, again, there is no real security here; if you have the path: you have the file.

Someone smart might post a great answer that shows you how to do it, but I'm skeptical that there is a way for you to (trivially) restrict access at the webserver level via application level knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, it was really informative and helpful.